# p:panel and p:fieldset issue with collapsed state when using ajax/update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using a *p:dialog* inside a form to perform a search. The dialog has a nested *p:panel* that is *toggable* and must be *collapsed* when opening the dialog.

```
<h:form>
  ...

  <p:commandButton value="open search" 
    actionListener="#{searchBean.initSearch}"
    process="@this"
    oncomplete="search_dlg.show()" 
    update="search" />

  <p:dialog id="search" widgetVar="search_dlg" visible="false">
    ...
     <p:panel header="..." toggleable="true" collapsed="true">
      ...
     </p:panel>

     <p:commandButton value="do search" 
       actionListener="..."
       process="search"
       oncomplete="search_dlg.hide()" 
       update="page" />

  </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

First time the dialog is opend by pushing *open search* button, the panel is collapsed as it should. But when it is then toggled open and the *do search* button is pushed and performs posting the dialog-part, the opend state remains when the dialog is opened later again. So it seems that the last collapsed state is saved in the component tree. Even the following does not change that behavior:

```
<p:panel header="..." toggleable="true" collapsed="#{searchBean.panelCollapsed}>
```

SearchBean:

```
private boolean panelCollapsed;

public void initSearch() {
   panelCollapsed = true;
}

public boolean isPanelCollapsed() {
   return panelCollapsed;
}

public void setPanelCollapsed(boolean panelCollapsed) {
   this.panelCollapsed = panelCollapsed;
}
```

So you would think, that performing `update="search"` would cause the collapsed-state beeing read from the bean. But it is not! The getter `isPanelCollapsed()` isn't even called!

Is there a good reason for this behavior or is this a bug in *p:panel* and *p:fieldset*?

Using PF 3.4.1 but since I could not find an entry in the changeLogs this issue should be the same in actual PF release 4.0.1.

Comment: Not really an answer but a workaround is described here:
http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=30862#p99198

IMO it makes code more unreadable but it helped me to reach the goal.

So my question still is: Is the behavior described above a bug or a feature?

Comment: I'm seeing this in PF 4, too.  For some reason the collapsed attribute is not being updated with the bean value.  I put some logging messages there to verify.  It's also intermittent.  Sometimes it works; sometimes it doesn't.  The workaround you have has the same issue.  toggle() is being called but it sometimes doesn't seem to update the component.  However, if I do it in the console, it works.  I put it int he document load handler just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I am using '
 p:layout fullpage="true", all the p:layoutUnit are unable to be collapsed in p:layout tag. Finally I found the reason is because p:layout tag is wrapped by h:form tag. The collapse function is working fine after I moved h:form into p:panel like following

```xml
<p:panel collapsed="true">
   <h:form>
   ...
   </h:form>
</p:panel>
```